# SQL JOIN - two teams, one logo database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two databases, one database(Games) contains hometeamID and visitorID. And the other database(Teams) contains all the logoNames and the teamID. (Games) hometeamID and visitorID are related to (Teams) by teamID.

I am wanting to run a SQl query that outputs the teams from the (Games) database but also shows the logos for each respective team. I want the output to look something like this.

```
<item>
     <hometeamID>
     <home_logo>
     <visitID>
     <visitor_logo>
</item>
```

When attempting to query using PHP, i use

```
SELECT *
FROM Games LEFT JOIN
     Teams
     on Games.homeID = Teams.teamID
```

I can get the first logo for hometeam fine, but when i use AND

```
SELECT *
FROM Games LEFT JOIN
     Teams
     on Games.homeID = Teams.teamID and Games.vistorID = Teams.teamID
```

I get nothing.

I am able to get the query to work, but i don't get the logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the second statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Games LEFT JOIN Teams on Games.homeID = Teams.teamID and Games.vistorID = Teams.teamID
```

You are correctly joining the two tables to get the information you need. However, with the AND statement you cause homeID = teamID AND teamID = visitorID. Therefore, we can rewrite this to say homeID = teamID = visitorID. This will never happen because homeID and visitorID will never be to same for a given entry.

In order to get the two sets of logos we need to do two joins in order to add the columns. So, something like:

```
SELECT Games.homeID, HomeTeam.logo as homeLogo,
       Games.visitorID, VisitorTeam.logo as visitorLogo
FROM Games LEFT JOIN Teams HomeTeam
    ON Games.homeID = HomeTeam.teamID
LEFT JOIN Teams VisitorTeam
    ON Games.visitorID = VisitorTeam.teamID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the great description! Solution worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You need two joins.  Obviously, `Teams.teamId` cannot be both `homeID` and `visitorId` (well, unless a team is playing itself), which is why your query returns no rows.

So, use two joins instead of one:

```
SELECT g.homeId, h.logo as home_logo,
       g.vistorId, v.logo as visitor_logo
FROM Games g LEFT JOIN
     Teams h
     ON g.homeID = h.teamID LEFT JOIN
     Teams v
     ON g.vistorID = v.teamID;
```